# VIP publish function not timing out when remote platform is dead

Tags: volttron

I am following the example in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39212536/in-volttron-how-to-use-vip-to-get-agents-talk-across-remote-platform-instances) to try to publish messages to a remote VOLTTRON platform, and it is working fine when the remote platform is running and set-up correctly. **However, when the remote platform is not running, the publish function remains blocking forever and won't time out.** This prevents detection of when the remote platform is not running, and also prevents execution of rest of the code.

```
from volttron.platform.vip.agent import Core, Agent
import gevent

def vip_publish(topic,message, address=None):
    retry = 3
    while retry>0:
        pub_agent = Agent(address=address)
        my_event = gevent.event.Event()
        pub_agent.core.onstart.connect(lambda *a, **kw: my_event.set(),my_event)
        agent_thread = gevent.spawn(pub_agent.core.run)
        my_event.wait()
        try:
            #The following line remains blocking forever when remote volttron platform is not running
            pub_agent.vip.pubsub.publish(peer='pubsub', topic=topic, message=message).get(timeout=1)
        except gevent.Timeout:
            print "Time-out"
            retry -= 1
        else:
            retry = 0
        agent_thread.kill()
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to [vip.pubsub.publish method does not timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903081/vip-pubsub-publish-method-does-not-timeout) as well this question.

The code for this agent isn't correct.  my_event.wait() does not throw an exception it returns a true or false value.

So instead the code should have something like:

```
if not my_event.wait(timeout=5):
    print('Bad thing here')
    sys.exit()
```

or you can use

```
with gevent.Timeout(timeout=5):
    event.wait()  # note not gevent
```

See https://github.com/VOLTTRON/volttron/blob/develop/volttron/platform/vip/agent/utils.py to see how we deal with this.